# Access vector by end indices

Tags: r, matrix, indices

I've always been wondering if there were a quick and clean way of selecting the k last element of a vector/matrix...

As far as I know, one can specify positives indices to extract values, negative indices to keep all apart specified indices, but is there a short cut for keeping the k last elements.

For now, considering a vector `vect` I've been using:

```
rev(rev(vect)[1:k])
```

which is not that bad but doesn't work if I want to keep the last k column of a matrix for example. In this case I write:

```
vect[(length(vect)-k+1) : length(vect)]
```

thanks !

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve with `vect[(length(vect)-k+1) : length(vect)]`.

Comment: Basically `tail` just hides `vect[(length(vect)-k+1) : length(vect)]` ; I was wondering if there where a direct command

Comment: No it's not.  `tail` has different `methods` depending on the input.